# How to convert a List object to an object of type com.avaje.ebean.PagingList

Tags: playframework, ebean

How to convert **List** to an **object of** `type com.avaje.ebean.PagingList`

I have a List object retrieved using the below

```
String sql ="select ....";
List list = Ebean.createQuery(XYZ.class, sql).findList();
```

Now, I would like to convert this to below object of type

```
com.avaje.ebean.PagingList
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Why not retrieving it as PagingList? Then you need nothing to convert, and you can use it as a regular `List`?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like: (untested code)

```
// String sql ="select ....";
// List list = Ebean.createQuery(XYZ.class, sql).findList();

PagingList<XYZ> yourList = Ebean.createQuery(XYZ.class, sql).findList();
List<XYZ> list = yourPagingList.getAsList();
```

Then you can use the PagingList and convert it from PagingList to List when needed.

Answer (score 0):

What about (tested code):

```
int pageSize = 10;
String sql ="select ....";
PagingList<XYZ> pList Ebean.createQuery(XYZ.class, sql).findPagingList(pageSize);
```

Then you can convert it to List:

```
List<XYZ> list = pList.getAsList();
```